# How translate a point on a circle?

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

I am trying to create a circle from the given radius and translate the circle.

```
edia = 10; %diameter
theta=linspace(0,2*pi, 100); %100 evenly spaced points.
radius = edia./2;
x = radius.*cos(theta);
y = radius.*sin(theta);
plot(x,y, 'k')
axis equal
axis([-edia, edia, -edia, edia]);
```

After creating a circle using the code, I have to translate it but I have no idea how to do it.

This is the circle that I have

[image]

and this is what I am suppose to get after translating

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this simple case, just add the shift directly.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
close all
edia = 10; %diameter
theta=linspace(0,2*pi, 100); %100 evenly spaced points.
radius = edia./2;
x = radius.*cos(theta);
y = radius.*sin(theta);
plot(x,y, 'k')
axis equal
axis([-edia, edia, -edia, edia]);

newX=3; newY=4;
hold on;
plot(x+newX,y+newY, '-.')
```